# Map Selector System in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, user-experience

I would like to implement in my project a "map selector" system with the maps scrolling in a horizontal list, and the map in the middle of the screen becomes the selected map, but I have no idea how to implement such a thing. I can't find any tutorial about it, and there are almost no Udemy courses that only focus on UI/UX. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi, SO is more for direct concrete questions and answers - your question is too broad and is better suited for something like reddit or the unity forums

Comment: Create a UI element with a horizontal layout group. Then create a button prefab that represent each of your maps and make a script that shows a picture of  said map in the UI picture background on hover over the button prefab.

Comment: @Sam when you say create a UI Element, you mean a GameObject right ? Or a Canvas ?